# Text in div moves around when using jQuery animate to expand height

Tags: jquery, html, css

On [this webpage](http://northviewhigh.com/index/fbla/1213/eb/tickets/), I have a set of buttons that, when clicked, the section below is going to expand to show more content. The instructions for the page fade out and the content for the selected section fades in.

The issue that I am currently experiencing is the fact that the text moves around as the section expands (click the "Graduate" button to see what I'm talking about). Here's the jQuery I'm using to make everything happen (full script file [here](http://northviewhigh.com/index/fbla/1213/eb/jquery/scripts.js)):

```
function expandTix(newHeight) {
    $('#tixcontainer').animate({
        height: newHeight + 'px'
    });
}
$('.gradbutton').click(function(){
    $('.startinfo').fadeOut();
    $('.gradinfo').fadeIn();
    expandTix(300);
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="tixcontainer">

    <div class="tixcontent startinfo">
        Select a ticket type to begin ordering your graduation tickets. 
    </div>

    <div class="tixinfo hidden gradinfo">
        You selected "Graduate"
    </div>

</div>
```

How can I make it so that the text does not jump around as it animates?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this **Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8NegC/

This will fit you need compared to this buggy one `:)` so that you can see the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/DpG6A/1/ (*Buggy demo to show the difference*)

rest will fit your need `:)`

**Code**

```
function expandTix(newHeight) {
    $('#tixcontainer').animate({
        height: newHeight
    }, 'slow', function() {
        $('.gradinfo').fadeIn();

    });

}
$('.gradbutton').click(function() {
    $('.startinfo').fadeOut();
    expandTix($('.startinfo').height());

});​
```

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of the text jumping around but now the startinfo div is jumping down when the animation starts. The height of the tixcontainer div also jumps back once the startinfo div is completely hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing explicit width on your #tixcontainer element.

**Add width:100% to your css file for the element #tixcontainer**

The problem you are seeing is because when .animate() runs, in between animation steps, it will add overflow:hidden to the animated element.

Since the element you are animating does not have explicit dimensions when overflow hidden is applied it will try to hide the contents and the parent element will loose it's calculated width so you need to explicitly set it